# ASUS ROG Gaming Center Key

Tags: asus-laptop

I bought a ASUS ROG laptop with 8 cores. Loving the performance, not the battery life.

My biggest gripe is with that special key on the number pad which fires off the "Gaming Center".

How do I reprogram that key? I returned my HP Omen for exactly this same reason.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the ASUS application in question?  It does not sound like you even use it.

Comment: I don't use it at all but there is no way to uninstall it. It came with the laptop.

Comment: If it's installed then it can be removed.  Have you tried removing all ASUS software from the installation?

Comment: @Ramhound, even if it can be uninstalled, how is that going to get my key to behave the way I want?

Comment: One you uninstall the software you can determine what the Key code is and then use a program like AutoHotKey to have it do whatever you want